# show image in angular6 and AspCore with Blob

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to display a list of products. This list also includes product photos. For example, include product name, product title, photo URL and. . . Is .

```
export interface Product {
   id:number;
   productTitle:string;
   productName:string;
   color:string;
   productImageName:string;
   price:number;
   gurantyMonth:string;
   gurantyCompanyName:string;
   catId:number;
   values:Productdetail[];
}
```

and i send request to server like this :

```
  public GetProductList():Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.url+'GetProductList',{headers:this.headers})
          .pipe(
                 tap(() => this.log(``)),
                 catchError(this.handleError<any>(''))
              );
 }
```

and this is `Headers` =>

`const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' })
};`

and my server Get this Address for :

```
file:///C:/Users/Mr-Programer/Downloads/585e4bcdcb11b227491c3396.png
```

my pictures is this Address and it return true Address but angular not show me picture and it say me `unsafe` .

**Back-end and Front-End in Separate Enviroment**

**Whats the Problem? How can I Solve this Problem and Show Image in Angular? How Can I Use The Blob in This?**

Comment: Server is in node ?

Comment: @SachinShah no . ASP Core

Comment: Issue is in uploading image from server side. Make sure you are upload image in proper path.

Comment: @SachinShah It upload image and put the image in Currect path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the Url as a SafeUrl. Use the package `DomSanitizer` to get the method `bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value: string): SafeUrl`. Read about it [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  exampleFunction(imageUrl: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i use the `Blob` ?

Comment: Have you included the return value in your template or the imageUrl as a string?

Comment: `<img src="{{data.productImageName}}">`

Comment: Try `<img [src]="exampleFunction(data.productImageName)">`.

Comment: Oh forgot the `return` statement, please try again with the correction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187421/discussion-between-mr-programer-and-ngfelixl).

Comment: it show me this error : `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Mr-Programer/Desktop/New%20folder/StoreFinal/StoreFinal/wwwroot/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/8.png`

Comment: Do you run `ng serve` or have you got another environment? This is propably a CORS error. I suggest to put your image in your projects `src/assets` folder and have the imageUrl `./assets/fileName.png`.

Comment: my image save in folder in server . this address in server

Comment: my server ASp Core and seprate in angualr enviroment

Comment: Do you serve the Angular application within your Aspnet Server? If so, serve a static folder on your server containing the image, and access the file from there. Local url might be something like `http://localhost:3000/folder/Image.png`.

Comment: You need to serve the file from your server. You can't access `file:\\\C:\` etc.

Comment: [check this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_static_files.htm)

Comment: its not my problem